# Incorrect link in \listoftables after \setcounter{table}{0}

Tags: tables, sectioning, table-of-contents, hyperref, longtable

I'm trying to put together a statistical analysis plan using LaTeX. This is something I've never tried before. I want to create a section at the end called table shells, but I'm running into a couple of problems.

The first happens when I use `\setcounter{table}{0}` followed by `\listoftables`. The idea is to list all of my table shells at the end without also listing tables that came earlier in the body of the document. I've included some sample code below to illustrate the problem.

When I run this code, the link on page 5 that should point to the first table shell (\S1) actually points to the first table in the body of the document. Interestingly, the problem doesn't seem to crop up if I use a `tabular` environment instead of `longtable` for the tables in the body. My actual document has a multi-page table in the body though. So I can't solve my problem that way. I'm also curious to know what is going wrong.

The second problem I'm struggling with is figuring out how to make my LoT look like a section with numbering. My understanding is that a LoT doesn't normally have this but I think it makes sense to have it in this particular context.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Paul

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% Margins %%

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in} 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}

%%%% Packages %%%%

\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[font={bf}]{caption}
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[
  pdfstartpage=30,
  pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
  bookmarks,
  bookmarksopen,
  pdfstartview=Fit,
  pdfview=Fit,
  colorlinks,
  linktocpage,
  linkcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue,
  pagebackref=true
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\newpage

\section{Text with Tables Before the Table Shells}

An initial table called Table \hyperref[tbl:another]{\ref{tbl:initial}}.

{
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{ *{3}{>{\centering}m{1.5in}} }
  \caption[]{An Initial Longtable}  \\ \hline
  \label{tbl:initial}
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
   \caption[]{An Initial Longtable (Continued)}  \\ \hline
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
\endhead
   \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
\endfoot
   \hline
\endlastfoot
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
\end{longtable}
}

\newpage

Another table called Table \hyperref[tbl:another]{\ref{tbl:another}}.

{
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{ *{3}{>{\centering}m{1.5in}} }
  \caption[]{Another Longtable}  \\ \hline
  \label{tbl:another}
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
   \caption[]{Another Longtable (Continued)}  \\ \hline
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
\endhead
   \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
\endfoot
   \hline
\endlastfoot
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
\end{longtable}
}

\newpage

%\section{Appendix B: Table Shells}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand\listtablename{Appendix A: Table Shells} 
\renewcommand\thetable{\S\arabic{table}}
\listoftables

\newpage

{
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{ *{3}{>{\centering}m{1.5in}} }
  \caption[First Table Shell]{First Table Shell} \\ \hline
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
  \caption[]{First Table Shell (Continued)} \\ \hline
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
\endhead
   \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
\endfoot
   \hline
\endlastfoot
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\ 
\end{longtable}
}

\newpage

\begin{table}[h]
\caption[Second Table Shell]{Second Table Shell}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcc} \hline
Column 1   & Column 2   & Column 3 \\ \hline
Col1, Row1 & Col2, Row1 & Col3, Row1 \\     
Col1, Row2 & Col2, Row2 & Col3, Row2 \\
Col1, Row3 & Col2, Row3 & Col3, Row3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\newpage

\begin{table}[h]
\caption[Third Table Shell]{Third Table Shell}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[c]{lcc} \hline
Column 1   & Column 2   & Column 3 \\ \hline
Col1, Row1 & Col2, Row1 & Col3, Row1 \\     
Col1, Row2 & Col2, Row2 & Col3, Row2 \\
Col1, Row3 & Col2, Row3 & Col3, Row3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue #1

Using the option `hypertexnames=false` when loading `hyperref` should solve your issue:

```
\usepackage[
  pdfstartpage=30,
  pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
  bookmarks,
  bookmarksopen,
  pdfstartview=Fit,
  pdfview=Fit,
  colorlinks,
  linktocpage,
  linkcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue,
  pagebackref=true,
  hypertexnames=false
]{hyperref}
```

### Issue #2

Add this code in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \section{\listtablename}%
      \@mkboth{%
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
         {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    }
\makeatother
```

---

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% Margins %%

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}

%%%% Packages %%%%

\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[font={bf}]{caption}
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[
  pdfstartpage=30,
  pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
  bookmarks,
  bookmarksopen,
  pdfstartview=Fit,
  pdfview=Fit,
  colorlinks,
  linktocpage,
  linkcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue,
  pagebackref=true,
  hypertexnames=false
]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \section{\listtablename}%
      \@mkboth{%
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
         {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newpage

\section{Text with Tables Before the Table Shells}

An initial table called Table \hyperref[tbl:another]{\ref{tbl:initial}}.

{
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{ *{3}{>{\centering}m{1.5in}} }
  \caption[]{An Initial Longtable}  \\ \hline
  \label{tbl:initial}
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
   \caption[]{An Initial Longtable (Continued)}  \\ \hline
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
\endhead
   \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
\endfoot
   \hline
\endlastfoot
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
\end{longtable}
}

\newpage

Another table called Table \hyperref[tbl:another]{\ref{tbl:another}}.

{
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{ *{3}{>{\centering}m{1.5in}} }
  \caption[]{Another Longtable}  \\ \hline
  \label{tbl:another}
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
   \caption[]{Another Longtable (Continued)}  \\ \hline
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
\endhead
   \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
\endfoot
   \hline
\endlastfoot
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
\end{longtable}
}

\newpage

%\section{Appendix B: Table Shells}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand\listtablename{Appendix A: Table Shells}
\renewcommand\thetable{\S\arabic{table}}
\listoftables

\newpage

{
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{ *{3}{>{\centering}m{1.5in}} }
  \caption[First Table Shell]{First Table Shell} \\ \hline
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
  \caption[]{First Table Shell (Continued)} \\ \hline
  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ \hline
\endhead
   \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
\endfoot
   \hline
\endlastfoot
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
XXXXX & XXXXX & XXXXX \\
\end{longtable}
}

\newpage

\begin{table}[h]
\caption[Second Table Shell]{Second Table Shell}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcc} \hline
Column 1   & Column 2   & Column 3 \\ \hline
Col1, Row1 & Col2, Row1 & Col3, Row1 \\
Col1, Row2 & Col2, Row2 & Col3, Row2 \\
Col1, Row3 & Col2, Row3 & Col3, Row3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\newpage

\begin{table}[h]
\caption[Third Table Shell]{Third Table Shell}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[c]{lcc} \hline
Column 1   & Column 2   & Column 3 \\ \hline
Col1, Row1 & Col2, Row1 & Col3, Row1 \\
Col1, Row2 & Col2, Row2 & Col3, Row2 \\
Col1, Row3 & Col2, Row3 & Col3, Row3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output (List of Tables):

[image]

If you now click on the number "6" next to the first entry you will be redirect to the right table.

Comment: Hi Karl, This works both in my sample code and in my actual document. Thanks very much for your help with this. Paul

Comment: @PaulMiller Happy about that. Remember that, if you want, you can accept the answer by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)).

Comment: Sorry. Am new to this. Found the tickmark and clicked on it. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @PaulMiller You're welcome

Comment: @karlkoeller very nice, thanks!